# Regular expression for URL with some peculiarities

Tags: .net, regex, twitter

I'm trying to set up a regular expression for a valid URL as understood by Twitter, this is, with this characteristics:

- It may only have [valid domain extensions](http://www.norid.no/domenenavnbaser/domreg.html)
- It may begin by http:// or https:// or none
- If it begins not by http:// nor by https:// then, it counts as a valid domain name if:

  - It's a valid domain extension and it has more than 2 letters (.com, .org, etc.)
  - It's a valid domain extension with 2 letters and it is writter in UPPERCASE (.CO, .ES, etc.)

So, my problem now is that I have separate regex for URLs with *http* and without it, and *http://example.com* is being count twice, once for *http* regex one for *non http* regex , this one should include a term to exclude http and https, here is where I fail with things like `"(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){0}"` or `"^(http:\/\/)"`.

**Basically this question reduces to: how can I compute http://example.com in a regular expression for *http prefixed URLS regex* and avoid it in and *non http prefixed URLS regex*, this is, avoid to compute example.com**

My code:

```
    Dim validDomainExtensions As String = "(aero|arpa|asia|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|biz|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|cat|com|coop|c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|d[ejkmoz]|edu|e[ceghrstu]|f[ijkmor]|gov|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|info|int|i[delmnoqrst]|jobs|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|mil|mobi|museum|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|name|net|n[acefgilopruz]|om|org|pro|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|travel|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw]){1}"

    Dim validDomainExtensionsIgnoreCase As String = "(aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel){1}"
    Dim validDomainExtensionsUpperCase As String = "(A[CDEFGILMNOQRSTUWXZ]|B[ABDEFGHIJMNORSTVWYZ]|C[ACDFGHIKLMNORSUVXYZ]|D[EJKMOZ]|E[CEGHRSTU]|F[IJKMOR]|G[ABDEFGHILMNPQRSTUWY]|H[KMNRTU]|I[DELMNOQRST]|J[EMOP]|K[EGHIMNPRWYZ]|L[ABCIKRSTUVY]|M[ACDGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|N[ACEFGILOPRUZ]|OM|P[AEFGHKLMNRSTWY]|QA|R[EOUW]|S[ABCDEGHIJKLMNORTVYZ]|T[CDFGHJKLMNOPRTVWZ]|U[AGKMSYZ]|V[ACEGINU]|W[FS]|Y[ETU]|Z[AMW]){1}"

    Dim validDomainName As String = String.Concat("[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)*[\.]{1}", _
                                                  validDomainExtensions, _
                                                  "([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?")

    Dim validDomainNameSinHTTP1 As String = String.Concat("[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)*[\.]{1}", _
                                                  validDomainExtensionsIgnoreCase, _
                                                  "([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?")

    Dim validDomainNameSinHTTP2 As String = String.Concat("[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)*[\.]{1}", _
                                                  validDomainExtensionsUpperCase, _
                                                  "([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?")

    Dim regxHTTP As New Regex(String.Concat("(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)+", validDomainName), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim regxSinHTTP1 As New Regex(String.Concat("(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){0}", validDomainNameSinHTTP1), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim regxSinHTTP2 As New Regex(String.Concat(validDomainNameSinHTTP2))

    Dim matchesHTTP As MatchCollection = regxHTTP.Matches(txtTweet.Text)
    Dim matchesSinHTTP1 As MatchCollection = regxSinHTTP1.Matches(txtTweet.Text)
    Dim matchesSinHTTP2 As MatchCollection = regxSinHTTP2.Matches(txtTweet.Text)

    textoSinUrls = regxHTTP.Replace(txtTweet.Text, "")
    textoSinUrls = regxSinHTTP1.Replace(textoSinUrls, "")
    textoSinUrls = regxSinHTTP2.Replace(txtTweet.Text, "")

    For Each match As Match In matchesHTTP
        txtUrlsDetectadas.Text = String.Concat(match.Value, vbNewLine, txtUrlsDetectadas.Text)

        If match.Value.Substring(0, 8) = "https://" Then
            NUrlsHTTPS += 1
        Else
            NUrlsHTTP += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each match As Match In matchesSinHTTP1
        'It fails here, as match.Value is actually example.com if I actually typed http://excample.com'

        If match.Value.Substring(0, 7) <> "http://" Then
            txtUrlsDetectadas.Text = String.Concat(match.Value, vbNewLine, txtUrlsDetectadas.Text)
            NUrlsHTTP += 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each match As Match In matchesSinHTTP2
        If match.Value.Substring(0, 7) <> "http://" Then
            txtUrlsDetectadas.Text = String.Concat(match.Value, vbNewLine, txtUrlsDetectadas.Text)
            NUrlsHTTP += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to combine regular expression with Substring as didn't find a way to do it in a regex. More info [here](http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/87765.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would create an alternation, 
the first case is the http(s)-case, the second is the non-http(s), where I'd check if the URL contained the domain condition.
Something like this:

```
(\A(?!=http)[your regex]|\A(?=.*\.(CO|ES|com|org))http[your regex])
```

The (?=.*.(CO|ES|com|org)) lookahead checks if there is a CO ES etc. somewhere in your string, without "eating it up".

Comment: I separated in different regular expressions as one is case sensitive and the others are case insensitive (HTtp is also valid). But don't understand the _http[your regex])_ at the end of the regex. thanks